# handling multiple clients using select

Tags: sockets, select, udp, serversocket

As i already asked similar questions but didn't get a solution. Hence i put this problem again with the whole code. Please tell me how can i acheive this goal

1) i have a client which sends to mainserver (127.0.0.1) a message and main server forwards it to   server2 (127.0.0.2)

2) Server2 sends a message to the mainserver and mainserver forwards it to client.

Problem 1) : Although i receive the datas from client but they are not sent to server2. 
Problem 2) :I dont receive any data from server2

```
    //SERVER
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/select.h>//use select() for multiplexing
#include <sys/fcntl.h> // for non-blocking

#define MAX_LENGTH 100000
#define PORT 1901

/* Select() params
 * int select(int n, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
 * FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);
 * FD_CLR(int fd, fd_set *set);
 * FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set *set);
 * FD_ZERO(fd_set *set);
*/

void error(char *message)
{
    perror(message);
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{

  // select parameters declared
  fd_set original_socket;
  fd_set original_stdin;
  fd_set readfds;
  fd_set writefds;
  struct timeval tv;
  int numfd, numfd2;

  // socket parameters declared
  int socket_fd_ob, socket_fd_hm;
  int bytes_read, bytes_sent;
  char address_length, address_length2;
  char recieve_data[MAX_LENGTH];
  char send_data[MAX_LENGTH];
  struct sockaddr_in server_address_ob, server_address_hm, client_address;
  int z = 0;

  //Socket creation done separately for both OBCU and HM communications
  if ((socket_fd_ob = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) 
  {
      error("socket()");
  }
  if ((socket_fd_hm = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) 
  {
      error("socket()");
  }


  fcntl(socket_fd_ob, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); //set socket to non-blocking
  fcntl(socket_fd_hm, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); //set socket to non-blocking

  // clear the set ahead of time
  FD_ZERO(&original_socket);
  FD_ZERO(&original_stdin);
  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  FD_ZERO(&writefds);

  // add our descriptors to the set (0 - stands for STDIN)
  FD_SET(socket_fd_ob, &original_socket);//instead of 0 put socket_fd_ob
  FD_SET(socket_fd_ob, &readfds);
  FD_SET(0,&original_stdin);
  FD_SET(0, &writefds);

  // the n param in select()
  numfd  = socket_fd_ob + 1;
  numfd2 = socket_fd_hm + 1;


  // wait until either socket has data ready to be recv()d (timeout 10.5 secs)
  tv.tv_sec = 0.7;
  tv.tv_usec = 500000;

  server_address_ob.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_address_ob.sin_port = htons(1901);
  server_address_ob.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  bzero(&(server_address_ob.sin_zero),sizeof(server_address_ob));

  server_address_hm.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_address_hm.sin_port = htons(1901);
  server_address_hm.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.2");
  bzero(&(server_address_ob.sin_zero),sizeof(server_address_hm));

  // Bind socket to the particular addresses

  if (bind(socket_fd_ob,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address_ob, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
  {
      error("bind()");
  }

  if (bind(socket_fd_hm,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address_hm, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
  {
      error("bind()");
  }

  address_length  = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
  address_length2 = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

  printf("\nMain server waiting for client to respond...\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  while (1)
  {
    readfds = original_socket;
    writefds = original_stdin;//problem
    int recieve = select(numfd, &readfds, &writefds,/*NULL,*/ NULL, &tv);
    int sent    = select(numfd2, &readfds, &writefds,/*NULL,*/ NULL, &tv);

    if (recieve == -1 || sent == -1) 
    {
      perror("select"); // error occurred in select()
    } 
    else if (recieve == 0 || sent == 0) 
    {
      printf("Timeout occurred!  No data after 1.5 seconds.\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
        // one or both of the descriptors have data
        if (FD_ISSET(socket_fd_ob, &readfds)) //if set to read
        { 
          FD_CLR(socket_fd_ob, &readfds);

        if (bytes_read = recvfrom(socket_fd_ob,recieve_data,MAX_LENGTH,0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address_ob, &address_length)>0)
        {       
        for (z = 0; z < bytes_read; ++z) {
          FD_ISSET(socket_fd_hm, &writefds);
          FD_CLR(socket_fd_hm, &writefds);
          //recvfrom speech recognition client and decide what to send to HM accordingly..
          send_data[bytes_read] = recieve_data[bytes_read];
          //block call, will wait till client enters something, before proceeding
          //send the corresponding to HM
          bytes_sent = sendto(socket_fd_hm,send_data,strlen(send_data)+1,0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address_hm, &address_length2); 
          fflush(stdout);
       }                  

          // 02x, #x,X
          printf("\n(%s , %d) rcvd: %s\n",inet_ntoa(server_address_ob.sin_addr),ntohs(server_address_ob.sin_port),recieve_data);
          printf("\n(%s , %d) sent: %s\n",inet_ntoa(server_address_hm.sin_addr),ntohs(server_address_hm.sin_port),send_data);
          recieve_data[bytes_read] = '\0'; //add null to the end of the buffer
          send_data[bytes_read] = '\0'; //add null to the end of the buffer
        }

        else if (bytes_read = recvfrom(socket_fd_hm,recieve_data,MAX_LENGTH,0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address_hm, &address_length)>0)
        {       
       for (z = 0; z < bytes_read; ++z) {
          FD_ISSET(socket_fd_ob, &writefds);
          FD_CLR(socket_fd_ob, &writefds);
          send_data[bytes_read] = recieve_data[bytes_read];
          //block call, will wait till client enters something, before proceeding
          //send the corresponding to HM
          bytes_sent = sendto(socket_fd_ob,send_data,strlen(send_data)+1,0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address_ob, &address_length2); 
          fflush(stdout);
       }                  

          // 02x, #x,X
          printf("\n(%s , %d) rcvd: %s\n",inet_ntoa(server_address_hm.sin_addr),ntohs(server_address_hm.sin_port),recieve_data);
          printf("\n(%s , %d) sent: %s\n",inet_ntoa(server_address_ob.sin_addr),ntohs(server_address_ob.sin_port),send_data);
          recieve_data[bytes_read] = '\0'; //add null to the end of the buffer
          send_data[bytes_read] = '\0'; //add null to the end of the buffer
        }

        else
        {
        printf("error noted");
        }   
        }  //end if set to read




    } //end else
  }//end while

  close (socket_fd_ob);
  close (socket_fd_hm);
  return 0;
}
```

Please suggest me with code samples. i am new to this topic and didn't have a broad view yet.

Thanks

Comment: First, there is one obvious discrepancy: sequence of two select()s for the same descriptor sets. If select() returns non-zero, sets are replaced with the only ready descriptors. Second, timeout for select can be updated, so you shall fill it again before each call. Third, better bzero() the whole sockaddr_in before filling with values, than only sin_zero. Fourth, there are uses of FD_ISSET without analyzing return value. Please fix all this and retry.

Comment: tv_sec can't be float; setting 0.7 to it results in 0, so, you effectively wait for 0.5 seconds in 1st select() and unknown time (due to chance timeout is overwritten) in 2nd and following ones.

Comment: BTW would you like switching to poll() instead of select()? It's easier to understand and use in most cases.

Comment: @Netch I am not so good with socket. I found some references and tried to do it. If i would use one socket?? how can i bind the server2 address? we can only bind one address ..isn't it? 

Can you show some reference in my code? what should i change??

Comment: A single socket can be bound to a single port (maybe automatically assigned) and, either to all local IPs or to a single one. If you need more, create more sockets. Then, use the only `select` or, better, `poll` for the whole descriptor set, both for send and receive. You don't have thousands of descriptors to separate them into different sets. On successful return from select/poll, analyze each descriptor readiness and perform corresponding actions (read/write). Remove useless FD_ISSET calls or really use their return values. That's enough for first iteration.